# golang parse yaml file struct challenged

Tags: go, yaml

Having a problem parsing this sort of yaml file. Using ["yaml.v2"](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/yaml.v2)

```
info:  "abc"

data:
  source:  http://intra
  destination:  /tmp

run:
  - id:  "A1"
    exe:  "run.a1"
    output:  "output.A1"

  - id:  "A2"
    exe:  "run.a2"
    output:  "output.A2"
```

I would like to get all the values of the YAML file so I have a basic struct like this

```
type Config struct {
  Info  string
  Data struct {
    Source  string `yaml:"source"`
    Destination  string `yaml:"destination"`
    }
 }
```

This works

But, I am not sure how to setup the struct for "run". The extra layer is confusing me.

```
type Run struct {
 ...
}
```

Comment: Your example of yaml file is not valid, and cause error using YAML parser of Ruby. are you supposing something like `{"run":[{"id":"A1","exe":"run.a1","output":"output.A1"},{"id":"A2",...}]}` in JSON?

Comment: fixed original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the OP's example of YAML is invalid. When value of `run` is list of dictionary it should be something like this:

```
info:  "abc"

data:
  source:  http://intra
  destination:  /tmp

run:
  - id:  "A1"
    exe:  "run.a1"
    output:  "output.A1"

  - id:  "A2"
    exe:  "run.a2"
    output:  "output.A2"
```

And here's the corresponding data struture, and example for decoding YAML into golang's structure.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"

    yaml "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

type Config struct {
    Info string
    Data struct {
        Source      string
        Destination string
    }
    Run []struct {
        Id     string
        Exe    string
        Output string
    }
}

func main() {
    var conf Config
    reader, _ := os.Open("example.yaml")
    buf, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(reader)
    yaml.Unmarshal(buf, &conf)
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", conf)
}
```

running this will output (added some indent for readability):

```
{Info:abc
 Data:{Source:http://intra Destination:/tmp}
 Run:[{Id:A1 Exe:run.a1 Output:output.A1}
      {Id:A2 Exe:run.a2 Output:output.A2}]
```

Comment: @NinjaGaiden sometimes it depends on the wether:). +1 for you.

Comment: Thanks. I hope its sunny today

Comment: How do I extract, id A1's, exe and output? Same for A2?

Comment: @NinjaGaiden A1's id can be accessed by `conf.Run[0].Id`. A2's id can be accessed by `conf.Run[1].Id`